# How to get the vector representation of a polynomial in GF(2)[x]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, polynomials, galois-field

I tried to multiply two polynomials *g*(*x*), *h*(*x*) ∈ GF(2)[*x*]. And I got the result as *c*(*x*). I would like to get the vector representation of *c*(*x*).

Here is the code I am sharing.

```
import galois 
GF = galois.GF(2)
g = galois.Poly([1, 0, 1, 1], field=GF)
h = galois.Poly([1, 1, 0], field=GF)
c = g * h
print(c)
```

The output I am getting is

```
x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x
```

but I would like to get output in vector form, i.e.,

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Any suggestion about how I can get the answer in vector form?

I tried the using calling the function

```
GF("c").vector()
```

but it is giving me the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `c.coeffs`. This gives:

```py
GF([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], order=2)
```

This form may be satisfactory for whatever you are trying to do.
If not, you can (among other things) turn it into a normal Python `list[int]` with `[int(i) for i in c.coeffs]`, yielding:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: You can also call NumPy's `.tolist()` on `c.coeffs`, which will automatically convert the `FieldArray` (`np.ndarray` subclass) into a native Python list.